# Getting an error when uploading the apk to the market

Tags: android

" An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. " is the error that I am getting when 
I try uploading my signed apk.. 
Once I was done with my app, I used Export signed application tool to generate the key. 
Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found that just SIGNING OUT and back int fixed the issue for me.  Using Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a different browser, or just wait.

This can help: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=7fff4999197c33c7&hl=en

Comment: Same thing happened to me yesterday, waited 24 hours still not able to upload. Switched to IE instead of Chrome, worked fine. Ironic thing about Google Play and Google Chrome...

Comment: Irony of fate, yesterday I had to switch browser because Google Maps crashed on Google Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Just log out . Log in again. And yep now it works :) . If not still working clear history and then try again logging in it will surely do. However google should look on to this issue

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same problem using FireFox, so I just switch to IE and it worked fine ...

Answer (score 0):

I logged out and then logged in again.  The new version is listed but a couple more steps involved.  Deactivate the currently published version and click the "Publish Now" button.

They need to fix this.  It is not intuitive by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, and solved it by:

1. Saving the apk as draft (instead of publishing it).
2. Deactivating the currently published version.
3. Publishing the draft apk.

Signing out and back in again didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the browser (IE/Opera) and re login didn;t work. So I logged out, remove all signed in gmail accounts from the browser(Chrome) and then logged in. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

I just spent hours trying to upload and publish a new version of my app using Firefox on the Google Developer site. Eventually I too found that just signing out and back in solved the problem.